# Does putting a tiny electrical current across the parietal lobe boosts maths ability?

Tags: neurology, mathematics

A [2010 BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/news/health-11692799) says:

> Applying a tiny electrical current to the brain could make you better at learning maths, according to Oxford University scientists.
>
> They found that targeting a part of the brain called the parietal lobe improved the ability of volunteers to solve numerical problems.

It feels so wrong, that I am inclined to call this an error.

Is this summarised result correct?

Comment: I believe [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982210012340) is the study, which was appropriately published in a journal called “*Current* Biology”.

Comment: I think this falls under Transcranial Direct Current Stimulation, which has been [asked about here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18575/is-transcranial-direct-current-stimulation-beneficial-for-a-healthy-human-brain)